# SQL syntax needed

Tags: sql

I got 3 tables in sql, which looks like this: (need sql syntax)

1

```
.xy8vx_users
-username
-email
-....
```

2

```
.xy8vx_rsform_submissions
-SubmissionId
-Username
-...
```

3

```
.xy8vx_rsform_submissions_values
-SubmissionId
-FieldName
-FieldValue
-...
```

I want to get:
 `xy8vx_users.username, and xy8vx_users.email`, which satisfies the condition

```
submission_values.FieldName = 'data2' AND submission_values.FieldValue = '10.03.2012'
```

I have spended 2 hours and nothing could somebody help me?

I had tryed this: (but not working)

```
SELECT sub.Username
FROM `xy8vx_rsform_submission_values` AS value
JOIN `xy8vx_rsform_submissions` AS sub ON value.SubmissionId = sub.SubmissionId
JOIN xy8vx_users ` AS users ON sub.Username = users.email WHERE value.FieldName = 'data2' AND value.FieldValue = '10.03.2012'`
```

Comment: You should consider posting your database schema, if you want anyone to be able to help you with this.

Comment: Try "spendeding" some time reading a book or an SQL tutorial. Also, the string "but not working" is not a built-in error message in any RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select xy8vx_users.username, xy8vx_users,email
from
submission_values 
inner join
submissions on 
submission_values.SubmissionId = submissions.SubmissionId
inner join
xy8vx_users on
submissions.Username = xy8vx_users.username
where 
submission_values.FieldName = 'data2'
and 
submission_values.FieldValue = '10.03.2012'
```